# Detect if another controller filtered repeated elements

Tags: angular

So in a controller I have an array of objects. And then in html I have this:

```
<div><input type="checkbox" ng-change="MyCtrl.checkboxesToggleAll()" />Check all</div>
<div ng-repeat="data in MyCtrl.objects track by $index">
<div>{{data.name}}</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" />Check this</div>
</div>
```

Now, when the checkbox "Check all" is clicked, all the other checkboxes are checked.

However, there is a problem. Somewhere else, in another controller, the "objects" in the repeat are filtered depending on selected parameters.
What happens than is that only elements in "repeat" that match the parameters are shown in the GUI.

The real problem is when I click on "Check all". Because even those checkboxes/elements that are not shown in the GUI (because of the filter) got selected.
I can see it (not in the GUI of course) because a variable holding all the checkboxes also contain those that are actually filtered in the GUI.

I hope the description was quite clear. What strategy should I use? I was thinking to use jquery to verify (when "Check all is clicked") which single checkboxes are actually showing in the GUI. And only "check" those.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly this is what you want.  You have multiple controllers which display a filtered list of elements.  You want to be able to select / deselect those elements and have that selection visible across other controllers/services.  You need the ability to select / deselect all.

I would build a service that is in charge of these objects.  You don't actually say what these objects are so I will call them orders.

```
export interface SelectableOrder {
  isSelected: boolean;
  order: Order;
}

@Injectable()
export class OrderService {

  private allOrders = new BehaviorSubject<SelectableOrder[]>([]);
  private filters = new BehaviorSubject<Filter[]>([]);

  constructor(private orderAccess: OrderAccess) {
    this.loadOrdersFromServer();
  }

  private loadOrdersFromServer() {
    this.orderAccess.getAllOrders().subscribe(orders => {
      this.allOrders.next(orders.map(order => ({
        isSelected: false,
        order: order
      }));
    });
  }

  private get visibleSelectableOrders() {
    return this.allOrders.combineLatest(this.filters, inputs => {
      const [allOrders, filters] = inputs;
      return allOrders.filter(selectableOrder => !this.isFiltered(selectableOrder.order, filters));
    });
  }

  get visibleOrders() {
    return this.visibleSelectableOrders.map(selectableOrder => selectableOrder.order);
  }

  private isFiltered(order: Order, filters: Filter[]) {
    //Implementation left to the user
    return false;
  }

  selectAllVisible() {
    this.visibleSelectableOrders.forEach(order => {
      order.selected = true;
    });
    this.allOrders.next(this.allOrders.value);
  }

  deselectAllVisible() {
    this.visibleSelectableOrders.forEach(order => {
      order.selected = false;
    });
    this.allOrders.next(this.allOrders.value);
  }

}
```